# Docker "Operation not permitted" issue on Windows

Tags: php, windows, docker, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to use Docker on Windows through Docker Toolbox, but I'm struggling to make it work. I've pulled Docker PHP image. For example, this simple `ls` command fails:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v /$(pwd):/home/projects php:7.0-cli ls -l /home/projects
ls: cannot open directory /home/projects: Operation not permitted
```

Also, any other operation within the mounted volume fails with `Operation not permitted` message.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a path issue with the volume mapping. Docker Toolbox uses Git Bash for the terminal, which uses `/c` as the root of the C: drive:

```
$ echo $(pwd)
/c/Users/elton
```

So your `/$(pwd)` is prepdening an extra forward slash. I'd try with a fully-qualified path first just to verify:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v /c/projects:/home/projects php:7.0-cli ls -l /home/projects
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work neither. I'm getting that same `Operation not permitted` message.